# Python: access to variables defined in nested class functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope, nested

Here I defined a class with custom `___mul__` operator.
Inside the `__mul__` operator I define a `_backward` function that use an argument to that function (`other` variable ).

How does python keep track of the `other` variable when I call the `_backward` function on `out`.

Does it internally keep track of the scope in which the function is defined?

```
class Value:
    
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.__rmul__ = self.__mul__
        
    def __mul__(self, other):
        out = Value(self.data*other.data)
        
        def _backward():
            print('Backward of ', self.data, other.data)
            
            
        out._backward = _backward
        return out
        
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        self.__mul__(self, other)

a = Value(10)
b = Value(5)

o = a*b

o._backward()
```

Output:

```
Backward of  10 5
```

Comment: its part of the closure

Answer (score 1):

In Python, first, it will check if there is a local variable (local to `_backward` function) called `other`. Then it will check in the outer scope which is `__mul__`, then it will check in the global scope, i.e., a variable declared in the zero level of indentation.

**local variable to `_backward`**

```py
class Value:
    ...
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        out = Value(self.data*other.data)
        
        def _backward():
            other =  Value(20)
            print('Backward of ', self.data, other.data)
            
            
        out._backward = _backward
        return out
```

**Output:**

```
Backward of  10 20
```

**`other` is a local variable to `__mul__`**

This is the code you are showing.

Comment: Interesting, so each call to `__mul__` has its own new persisted scope? So if I make 10,000 `__mul__` calls, python will keep track of 10,000 scopes till the program ends.

Comment: @Saurabh7, correct, whenever `__mul__ ` is called, it will create a new scope which will disappear when the call ends. In fact, that is what happens in any function call.

Comment: But the scope is still there after `a*b` is ended. I call `o._backward() ` after and its still works later.

Comment: `__mul__` will be called when you execute `a*b`, and the value of `other` will set at that moment. Any time you call `_backward`, it will have the value that was set when `a * b` was executed.

Comment: @Saurabh7 no, just as long as the function object exists